# How do I confirm the correct Robots.txt File is being used?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I have various stag and dev domains for a project I am working on and ultimately will have the actual production environment. I have created two `robots.txt` files:

1. `robots.txt`
2. `robots-nocrawl.txt`

The first is of course the standard file that I want to run on production and allow google to crawl.  I don't want my dev and stag domains indexed, so I want `robots-nocrawl.txt` fired when those domains are accessed, this file simply has `Disallow /`.

I have added the needed code the `.htaccess` file, see below, and moved the changes to my dev environment.  I can see that the nocrawl file is there, but pulling up the URL, but how to a check/confirm that the `robots-nocrawl.txt` file is the one being used when I am in dev/stag? I could not find a way to test this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stag\.mollywade\.([a-z\.]+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mollywade\.([a-z\.]+)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$  /robots_nocrawl.txt [L]
```

Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that it is working as intended you simply make the necessary request. For example:

- `example.com/robots.txt` should return the contents of `robots.txt`.
- `stag.example.com/robots.txt` should return the contents of `robots_nocrawl.txt`.
- `dev.example.com/robots.txt` should return the contents of `robots_nocrawl.txt`.

HOWEVER, you have a couple of critical errors in your current `.htaccess` file that will prevent this from working:

- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^/robots\.txt$` will never match in a per-directory `.htaccess` context. There should be no slash prefix. This should be `^robots\.txt$`.
- You have `OR`'d both conditions which would (if it was not for the above pattern failing to match) result in the `RewriteRule` executing unconditionally!

So, these directives should be written as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(stag|dev)\.mollywade\.([a-z.]+)
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$  /robots_nocrawl.txt [L]
```

You might as well combine these two conditions into one, then you can remove the `OR` flag altogether. There is no need to escape a literal dot when used inside a character class. The trailing `$` is superfluous since the regex is greedy by default.

> this file simply has `Disallow /`

I assume that is just a typo in your question, as you are missing a `:`. It should be `Disallow: /`.

Comment: That ReWriteCond, looks so cool, but it is not working.  I am testing on my local env at the moment.  I should get the same results, correct, local vs dev, I mean?   I getting **This rule was not met.** when testing using [https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/]. and if i go to the robots.txt file from my local, i see the standard file.  Yes I confirmed nocrawl file is there, spelling is correct, has only `Disallow: /` in it.

Comment: Whoa -- never-mind - **IT WORKS!!!** - thank you.  I finally thought to clear the cache and your **cool** code syntax works and your pointers have the nocrawl showing while in my local.  Thanks so much and bit thanks for the explanations.  Helped so much.  Take care.